# Django - Prefetch filter does not work on Many to Many model

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I want an endpoint for Group that filters Credits objects on week and year. Group has a Many to Many relation with 'through' arg to Membership. Membership ForeignKey to User. Credits ForeignKey to User.

I have the following Models:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="memberships", 
    through='Membership')
    
class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="membership", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
class Credits(models.Model):
    credits = models.IntegerField()
    year = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[0])
    week = models.IntegerField(default=date.today().isocalendar()[1])
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="credits", 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = NameField(max_length=25, unique=True,                              
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Serializers:

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='user.username')
    credits = CreditsSerializer(source='user.credits', many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('id', 'is_admin', 'user_id', 'username', 'credits')
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

        depth = 1


class GroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    memberships = MembershipSerializer(source='membership_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'memberships')
```

My Group view is:

```
class GroupSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    lookup_field = 'name'
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        year = self.request.query_params.get('year', None)
        week = self.request.query_params.get('week', None)
        name = self.request.query_params.get('name', None)

        if name and week and year is not None:

            prefetchCredits = Prefetch('members__credits', 
            queryset=Credits.objects.filter(year=year, week=week), to_attr='credit_objs')

            group = Group.objects.filter(name__iexact=name).prefetch_related(prefetchCredits)

            return group
```

The filter on Credits doesn't work. I've used this view structure before where the filter on Prefetch does work but the Models did not have a Many to Many relation.

I've tried to iterate over prefetchCredits to filter out the correct objects but I get an error: 'Prefetch' object is not iterable

I keep getting the structure below. Only one credits object should be shown with the year and week filter.

```
[
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Group2",
        "memberships": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "user_id": 2,
                "username": "test1",
                "credits": [
                    {
                        "credits": 800,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 41
                    },
                    {
                        "credits": 1000,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 40
                    },
                    {
                        "credits": 996,
                        "year": 2020,
                        "week": 39
                    }
                ],
```

Comment: You can not iterate over a `Prefetch` object. The `Prefetch` object does not store any data, it is just a representation of a prefetch task.

Comment: You can make use of a `to_attr` to store the filtered values. Can you share the `GroupSerializer`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for your fast reply. I've added the Serializers

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How would you make use of the to_attr in this case?

Comment: I've added to_attr and stored the objects from it in a list. Then added a new filter that filters on the objects in the list but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct connection between the model 'Group' and the class 'Credit', so it is not possible to prefetch the credits directly.

First you need to prefetch the related members (Membership) and use multilevel prefetching to include the credits of that membership.

It is possible to use prefetching on the queryset inside of a prefetch to make a multilevel prefetching structure.

```
prefetchCredits = Prefetch('user__credits', queryset=Credits.objects.filter(year=year, week=week))
prefetchMembership = Prefetch(
    'membership_set', 
    queryset=Membership.objects.prefetch_related(prefetchCredits)
)
group = Group.objects.filter(name__iexact=name).prefetch_related(prefetchMembership)
```

Also the name of the Credits Prefetch is changed to 'users__credits' to match the name of the serializer 'source'.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for